# π-separable group and subnormal series

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to show that if $G$ has a subnormal series, then $G$ is $\pi $-separable group. It is enough to show that ${N_i} \triangleleft G$ for every ${N_i} \triangleleft {N_{i + 1}}$ in series. But I can not go on.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing group theory if you're a truck.

Comment: Edited. @Mustafa probably meant he is stuck.

Comment: You must have missed out some assumptions, because every group has a subnormal series $1 < G$. Do you mean perhaps a subnormal series in ehich every factor is a $\pi$-group or a $\pi'$-group?

Comment: Yes, I exacly meant what you said, Derek Holt. Is there any hint to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let G has a subnormal series $\left\{ e \right\} = {N_0} \triangleleft {N_1} \triangleleft  \cdots  \triangleleft {N_k} = G$ with π and π′ factors. By induction on $k$, if 
${{N_{k - 1}}}$ is a π-separable, then we have a characteristic series $\left\{ e \right\} = {M_0} \triangleleft {M_1} \triangleleft  \cdots  \triangleleft {M_{k - 1}} = {N_{k - 1}} \triangleleft {N_k} = G$ with π and π′ factors, as desired.
Note that ${M_i}$ char ${N_{k - 1}} \triangleleft {N_k} = G$ and so ${M_i} \triangleleft {N_k} = G$.